# Принудительно открыть сайт с неверным сертификатом Firefox

Tags: firefox, https

Имеется сайт с неверным сертификатом. Его нужно открыть. На попытку "добавить исключение" Firefox пишет Статус сертификата - неверный сайт, и варианты получить сертификат снова, или просмотреть сертификат. Как его открыть принудительно?

Comment: Скриншот при нажатии на «добавить исключение» можно? А то не совсем понял

Answer (score 3):

Для этого надо на странице с ошибкой нажать кнопку «Дополнительно», затем «Добавить исключение...», потом в диалоговом окне щёлкнуть «Подтвердить исключение безопасности».

[image: Снимок экрана с окном браузера]
[image: Снимок экрана с диалоговым окном]

Comment: Нашёл. У меня эта кнопка в окно не влезла, поэтому я её и не увидел. Когда поменял размеры окна, нашёл.