# Принудительно открыть сайт с истекшим сертификатом Chrome или Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, https, firefox, сертификат

Когда даже верный и легитимный https сертификат сайта истек, последние версии браузеров Chrome или Firefox не дают открыть сайт. А при разворачивании спойлеров нигде нет кнопки "пропустить", "игнорировать", "все равно перейти на сайт" и т.д. Как быть?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/631264/Принудительно-открыть-сайт-с-неверным-сертификатом-firefox?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Chrome флаг **--ignore-certificate-errors** в свойства ярлыка.